# Postfix Folders

Tags: directory, postfix-mta, maildir

When I retrieve messages (with imap) the folder /home/user/mail is created while my config files (postfix and dovecot) redirects to /home/user/Maildir folder, and Maildir folder contains emails I want to get with imap !

I made a symbolic link between these folders and now with android I can retrieve messages stored in strange folders. With ThunderBird I can not explore folders. I see that dovecot creates an .imap folder where messages are finally stored, but not like expected.

Does somebody knows the mistake I did ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It was due to a bad dovecot config !

Lines added  to **/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf** :

```
ssl = yes

auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
passdb {
  args = dovecot
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```